# How to change files in discord.js by using commands?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

I tried to many things the thing. But I m not able to change the config file by using the command. I want to add channel id in that config

````js
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('../config.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

let owner = process.env.OWNER.split(',')
if(!owner.includes(message.author.id)) {
  return message.reply("This command is not made for everyone")
}
   if (message.channel.type === "dm" || message.author.bot || message.author === client.user) return; // Checks if we're on DMs, or the Author is a Bot, or the Author is our Bot, stop.

 fs.writeFile('./config.json', args[0], (err) => {
         if (err) console.log(err)
    })
  message.channel.send("Done")
}

exports.help = {
  name: "wtp",
  category: "General",
  description: "Add this channel into WTP",
  usage: "wtp <channel_id>"
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it like this, add/change variable of config and then save it.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('../config.json')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    let owner = process.env.OWNER.split(',')
    if(!owner.includes(message.author.id)) return message.reply("This command is not made for everyone")


    if (message.channel.type === "dm" || message.author.bot || message.author === client.user) return;  // Checks if we're on DMs, or the Author is a Bot, or the Author is our Bot, stop.

    if (args.length === 0) return message.reply('Pls mention a channell')
    let targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.get(args[0])
    if (!targetChannel) return message.reply('Cant fin`d channel')
    config.channed_id = targetChannel.id


 fs.writeFile('./config.json',JSON.stringify(config) , (err) => {
         if (err) console.log(err);
         message.channel.send("Done")
    })
}

exports.help = {
  name: "wtp",
  category: "General",
  description: "Add this channel into WTP",
  usage: "wtp <channel_id>"
};
```